# How to store html label as a php variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've done a bit of research and it seems I haven't found the answer anywhere. I'm wondering how I would store an HTML label as a variable. I have a label set in html and I would like to store it into a variable in php thus storing it again into my mysql database.

I tried setting the variable to the html name hoping that it would pick it up somehow.

```
//define variables and set to empty values
$adtitle = $email = $price = $message = $category = $Studname = "";


//Connecting to the database and table
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name); 

if($con->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}

//Get values from form, check whether or not values have been entered before submitting
if(isset($_POST['ad'])){ $adtitle = $_POST['ad']; }
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; }
if(isset($_POST['price'])){ $price = $_POST['price']; }
{ $Studname= $_POST['MyAdvertlabel']; }
```

'Studname' is the name of the variable and
MyAdvertlabel is the label i'm trying to store.

Have no idea what to do. Any link or reference would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: when you say `label` do you mean of this type `<label for='studname'>blah</label>`?

Comment: @RamRaider Sorry, I meant to say it's a normal field like <h2 id="Myadvertlabel"</h2>

Comment: so what do you want? you want to store the innerhtml of `h2`?

Comment: @Lai Ye, I another php file the label for the h2 is set to data coming from the database. So i'd like to save the label once its been changed so I can use it again elsewhere. Does that make sense?

Comment: You'll only be able to do that if you use javascript to submit the form - javascript can access the various attributes of html elements easily so you could append whatever `labels` to the form data before submitting

Comment: I also have a solution which is same as the solution proposed by @RamRaider